# (FASM) How to call properly a WinAPI like FindFirstFile and FindNextFile without use invoke?

Tags: winapi, calling-convention, fasm

My problem is the following: I have a program that looking for in the current directory for a specific file extension. The code works if I use invoke macro included in FASM. But I need call winAPI using the call instruction directly, and pushing their parameters in the stack.

I have tried this, but don't works and crashes my program:

```
;Push parameters for the function
push FIND_STRUCT     ;Put in the stack the address of FIND_STRUCT
push file_extension  ;File extension
call FindFirstFile   ; find the first *.fly
```

Please, Can somebody explain me how to call properly a WinAPI like FindFirstFile and FindNextFile??? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What does the ```invoke``` expand to? If you compile the code using ```invoke``` and then disassemble it, what do you see?

Comment: @xmojmr Thanks for read my question; I see code like my fragment used by me.

Comment: **1)** In order to get help, please provide [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **2)** The ```lpFindFileData``` argument for the [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx) must be allocated by you **3)** Get a good debugger and debug, step into, inspect memory, compare the code that works (the ```invoke```) and your code, every bit that is different matters. Assembly language is about bit-perfect coding

Comment: @xmojmr Thanks for your answer. I solved my problem enclosing in square brackets the name of the API, like this [FindFirstFile]. I believe that the API name is a pointer. Am I right???

Comment: It is not visible from your minimalistic code, but usually the API name will be a "pointer" either if you link it as an entry in the PE import table (http://win32assembly.programminghorizon.com/pe-tut6.html) or as a function loaded dynamically by [LoadLibrary & GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx). Anyway you should be able to find some useful answers at [Tomasz Grystarsz's Flat Assembler Message Board](http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=2527)

Comment: @xmojmr I have read your links and they are very useful. Thanks for answer me. My problem now is fixed

Comment: I was glad to help. Welcome to Stack Overflow and happy hacking - coder :v: If you write [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) you may get some points and future readers may find their answer more easily than by digging inside comments

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the API name could be a pointer. If I am right, the way to invoke a API name is enclosing in square brackets the API name, like this: `[API_name]`. This trick works at least for my FASM assembler and me.

If you don't use square brackets, you are calling the address of the pointer, not the pointed address. By this reason, use square brackets and enclose in them the API name, to call the API address, instead its pointer address.

I expect that the answer to my question can be useful for another people with the same problem.